# Can I get order guarantees when I make external stage and copy into snowflake?

Tags: amazon-s3

Suppose S3 divides folders by date and has data underneath them.
example)
s3://test/05/10/05101.csv
s3://test/05/11/05102.csv
At this time, if the url of the external stage is set to s3://test/05/
Loads both 10/05101.csv and 11/05102.csv.

1. How can I guarantee the order for those two files?
   Please let me know how to copy in by date
   05101.csv first copy into -> 05102.csv order
2. If that external stage is made into an external table
   Does the result come out in the order of the files at the time?
   Or do the mixed select results mix?
3. For external stage, how do you separate and exclude files that have been read once?

Any help is much appreciated.